# Build dictionary from file and os.listdir python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, for-loop

I'm using os.listdir and a file to create a dictionary. I'm getting keys and values from them respectively.

os.listdir gives me:

```
EVENT3180
EVENT2894
EVENT2996
```

and from the file I get:

```
3.1253   -32.8828   138.2464
11.2087   -33.2371   138.3230
15.8663   -33.1403   138.3051
```

The main problem is that my final dictionary has different keys but always the same value which is not what I want. What I'm trying to get is:

```
{'EVENT3180': 3.1253   -32.8828   138.2464, 'EVENT2894': 11.2087   -33.2371   138.3230, 'EVENT2996': 15.8663   -33.1403   138.3051}
```

So I think my code is looping over the keys but not over the values. Anyway, my code so far:

```
def reloc_event_coords_dic ():
    event_list = os.listdir('/Users/working_directory/observed_arrivals_loc3d')
    adict = {}
    os.chdir(path) # declared somewhere else
    with open ('reloc_coord_complete', 'r') as coords_file:
        for line in coords_file:
            line = line.strip() #Gives me the values
            for name in event_list: # name is the key
                entry = adict.get (name, [])
                entry.append (line)
                adict [name] = entry
            return adict
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to loop over the filenames and the lines of the input file simultaneously. Replace your nested loops with

```
for name, line in zip(event_list, coords_file.readlines()):
    adict.setdefault(name, []).append(line.strip())
```

where I took the liberty of compressing your loop body into one line.

If the amount of data to be processed is extremely large, then replace `zip` with its lazy cousin `izip`:

```
from itertools import izip

for name, line in izip(event_list, coords_file):
    # as before
```

Btw., doing a `chdir` in the middle of a function just to grab a single file is a code smell. You can easily open the right file with `open(os.path.join(path, 'reloc_coord_complete'))`.

Comment: That works and I suck because I spent two days on this!! I think I have a problem with for loops.....thanks very much for that!